# javascript- accessing elements from dialog box

Tags: javascript

I am producing a dialog box. The same element is present on both the main page and the dialog box. how to access the element on the dialog box from a javascript function?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how you are *producing* this dialog box? Ideally show your code.

Comment: Please, give use an example HTML code, as by your given description, there could be ANY html structure, which defines selector, that you need.

Comment: The same element **can't** be in two places at the same time. If you try to add an element to a node then the element is removed from whereever it started.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would access it if it wasn't in a dialog box. With getElementById or some DOM function. Please give us some more information or a code snippet if this doesn't help you (like how are you invoking this dialog box and whats the element in it..).